# Trigger a Java program on startup of some windows service or program

Tags: java, windows, triggers, operating-system, execution

I want my Java program or say some method within my class to be triggered when i start some Windows program(Application) .For example  i want my program start executing(Trigger) when i start Realplayer.

Comment: This is not really a Java related question, it is OS (Windows in this case) programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a psuedo-code of what you have to do:

1. Java application (Listener), registered as a Windows Service and runs on system stratup.
2. Listener application keep listening until some .exe file is opened.
3. Listener execute code (or call another application)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a jar and then use some sort of  Java Service Wrapper.... Still not sure.

What you actually require is to register a service in the Windows services.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with DOS...

```
@echo off
start path\to\someApplication
start path\to\javaApplication
```

Enter the above code in notepad and save it as `whateverNameYouWant.bat`

When you run it, the batch file will launch the application you specified in the code **AND** the Java (`.jar`) application you specified in the code.